# how to add fixed floating overlay image to google Map in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to add an image overlay that stays at center of the map when you move and get the location of the map. I tried to used marker but they stayed at specific location and also the same with groundoverlay. So I just want an image that stay in the centre of the map view. I have few ideas on how to do it but I'm trying to get the best solution. One of my idea is to use relative layout and overlay the image on top of the MapView but I think this may cause problems. let me what's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`FrameLayout` containing both `SupportMapFragment` (or `MapView`) and `ImageView`.

Simplest solutions are always the best.

Comment: Thanks I have done directly through XML. it works nicely so far.